# play m3u8 video on google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http-live-streaming

I can play [NASA's m3u8 HLS transmission](http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/NTV-Public-IPS.m3u8) or Apple's [sample m3u8 feed](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8) quite easily on Google chrome on a windows 7 64-bit desktop machine. But when I try to play my own m3u8 file in chrome by serving it through my nginx server it gets downloaded as a VLC file and I have to start VLC separately to play it. I can play the same file on a MAC using safari and on iPhone without problems.

I know playing my own m3u8 on chrome should work since NASA's m3u8 HLS transmission works fine on chrome. What am I doing different?

Appreciate any help/pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this bug report

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54198

it seems like they don't plan on implementing it

They are considering mpeg-dash as an alternative